# Excel, use conditional formatting to highlight dates in current fiscal year?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, date

In Excel 2016, I'm trying to use conditional formatting to highlight dates in a current fiscal year, but I can't figure out how to write the formula correctly. The fiscal year goes from 10/01/19 to 09/30/20. I looked around at different solutions using MONTH, YEAR, and TODAY, but I don't understand how to put them together into what I want.

And ideas?

Comment: Please read https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask . Questions should show that you have *thoroughly* researched your topic. You mention some functions but not how you have tried to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple way is to Create your conditional formatting and select "Format only cells that contain". Enter the range of dates 10/01/20219 and 09/30/2020 (Excel will convert them for you as it on the image below `=43739` and `=44104`). Set the color, then Ok, OK.

[image: IMG:]

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there was an easier way to do this that was evading me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula. Change the `$C4` reference to be the top cell in your applies-to range.

```
=OR(AND(YEAR($C4)=2019,MONTH($C4)>9),AND(YEAR($C4)=2020,MONTH($C4)<10))
```

This will also work:

```
=AND($C4>DATE(2019,9,30),$C4<DATE(2020,10,1))
```

[image]